# How do front end secure JWT token

Tags: next.js, jwt, refresh-token

I'm developing an app using NextJS and Spring Boot. I'm using JWT authentication in spring security, so i made an endpoint to accept the user's credentials and return a JWT token upon sucessful login attempt.

But, now i am wondering what is the best way to store the token in the front end, and should i use a refresh token mechanism?

I have read many articles about this, and i got more confused every time i read another one, here are my thoughts:

1. I know that i need to send the token in the request header as a bearer token, so i think i can't store it in cookie.
2. Because of that, my options are session storage and local storage, and because of its longevity, i think local storage is better for this case.
3. I think an can encrypt the token before storing it so that the token can't be used even if its stolen
4. So all i have to do is make a component to parse the token, and if the token hasn't expired, the user will be able to access the content.

After all that, i read that storing it in local storage can lead to XSS attacks, but does NextJS already sanitize user's input from XSS attacks? So is my method secure enough?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to store a JWT in the browser securely, thats one of the reason as why you should not use JWTs as a session.

JWTs should not be handed out to browsers, as you have seen they can be stolen through XSS attacks, you can’t logout a user, you can’t logout all devices, the token can be stolen in man in the middle attacks, be used in CSRF attacks, the list goes on.

Just because you might be secured from an XSS does not mean you are secured from other attacks.

Also just because you are secured now does not mean you will be tomorrow. What if there is a vulnerability in a third party dependency? Thats not your code.

Real security uses cookies between the frontend and backend and then the cookie is exchanged for a token that is used internally between microservices in the backend.

Most people/tutorials that use JWTs in browsers have never built real security sadly.

Comment: is there an article or tutorial that i can follow for the frontend and backend cookie sharing? Thanks for your knowledge!